# How do i understand and customize this annotation in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

When i type something in Jupyternotebook by vscode and  hover over the variable,  some hints appear above.

What does that mean? i thought str was a object of class str.

Comment: Have you defined a variable named `str` somewhere previously in your code?

Comment: That annotation is telling you that you redefined `str` to be a variable containing a list of integers. So search your code for `str =`

Comment: Although it's a really bad idea to do so, Python allows what is called "shadowing" of basic types and functions like `str` and `print()`. It looks like someone did something like `str = [1, 2, 3]` before you wrote that line.

Answer (score 0):

> x=str(5)

If we only use the code you show, the IntelliSense we get should be like this:

[image]

So I think it's possible that you defined `str` before the line and assigned type **list** to this three letters "str".

So, this "str" is not the same as type **Str**. It's just a list named "str". **str** is a function and [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) existing in Python language. We should avoid these characters defined in Python in our code writing.

At the same time, if you want to call the content in the list, please use square brackets **[5]** instead of parentheses **(5)**.

Here is my example:

```
newList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] #It is better not to use "str", which is a built-in function in Python
x = newList[5]
print(x)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a decent answer, but I think you should emphasize 1) That `str` is a built-in and what [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) is, and 2) That it's considered very poor practice in general to shadow built-ins. Also there is no type `String`. `str` is a type and also a function in python.

Comment: @thisisrandy yes, your suggestion is very reasonable. I've edited my answer.